# converter valor em 2 casas decimais em JS

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte script:

```js
var x = "202101000000";
var y = 0;


//bilhao

if(x.length >= 10 && x.length <= 12){
 if (x.length == 10){
  y = x.substr(0,1);
 }else if(x.length == 11){
  y = x.substr(0,2);
 }else if(x.length == 12){
  y = x.substr(0,3);
 }
  if(y.length == 1){
   document.getElementById('totalneuro').innerHTML = y + ' bilhão';
  }else{
   document.getElementById('totalneuro').innerHTML = y + ' bilhões';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="totalneuro"></div>
```

Ocorre que ele me dá como resultado do valor, o número "202 bilhões", quando gostaria que o valor viesse com 2 casas decimais, no caso, "202,10 bilhões". Como poderia resolver isso? Caso alguém saiba como fazer esse código menor e puder me ajudar, agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Você está dando `substr` no valor de `x`, pegando apenas as três primeiras casas da `String` de `202101000000`. Se você quiser acrescentar as casas decimais, você deve inserir uma vírgula e o restante das casas no limite de 2 após essa verificação:

```js
var x = "202101000000";
var y = 0;


//bilhao

if(x.length >= 10 && x.length <= 12){
 if (x.length == 10){
  y = x.substr(0,1) + "," + x.substr(1, 2);
 }else if(x.length == 11){
  y = x.substr(0,2) + "," + x.substr(2, 2);
 }else if(x.length == 12){
  y = x.substr(0,3) + "," + x.substr(3, 2);
 }
  if(y.length == 1){
   document.getElementById('totalneuro').innerHTML = y + ' bilhão';
  }else{
   document.getElementById('totalneuro').innerHTML = y + ' bilhões';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="totalneuro"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia manipular o valor como um número, ao invés de uma `String`. Exemplo:

```
var numero = Number("22101000000");
if(numero >= 1000000000 && numero < 1000000000000) {
    var numeroReduzido = Math.floor(numero / 10000000) / 100;
    var textoFinal = numeroReduzido.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + (numero >= 2000000000 ? " bilhões" : " bilhão");
    document.getElementById('totalneuro').innerHTML = textoFinal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer com o seguinte código:

```js
let x = '3710000000';


    function format(num){
      if(num < 1000)
        return num.toString();
      if(num < Math.pow(10,6))
        return (num / 1000).toFixed(2) + " k";
      if(num < Math.pow(10,9))
        return (num / 1000000).toFixed(2) + " Mi";
      if (num < Math.pow(10,12))
        return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + " Bi";
      return (num / Math.pow(10,12).toFixed(2) + " Tri") 
    }
    
    document.getElementById('totalneuro').innerHTML = format(x);
```